# FSharp interactive on CentOS 6.2 with Mono 2.10.2 won't run as non-root

Tags: f#, mono, centos, fsi

Hopefully this has not been asked/answered before, but I haven't found anything that fits my issue.

I installed mono on CentOS 6.2 as described [here](http://blog.ygraphix.net/en/2011/05/15/installer-mono-2-10-sous-centos-avec-yum/) using an rpm and then downloaded FSharp-2.0.0.0.  I got it all set up and fsi works great (as long as I pass it the option --gui-) while as root.  However, when I try to do it as a plain user I get an error telling me something about not being able to access the registry.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I'm not sure what the issue is (I've never used CentOS before, but a lab I work in does and I want to put FSharp on it for data processing -- thus I have to use CentOS, which I've read can be troublesome with mono).  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know little about CentOS, but the error message seems fairly clear, the mono process running fsi.exe does not have access to a file (the file path is given in the message). So it should be just a matter of running as root to give yourself access to the file, or better yet granting the current user access to this file via chmod (or similar tool).

Comment: Ok, that's pretty obvious, I guess.  I made that file read and writable by anyone for now and it runs just fine. Does anyone know if there are other files that could cause these permission issues?